# Writing a bash script to run c++ code on raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I have a c++ code which i have compile and this is how i run the c++ code in the terminal. `./executedfile inputargument.txt`. 
 Am trying to write a bash script that can run the command but am having challenges

Comment: _"but am having challenges"_ Could you elaborate please? That's simply too vague to diagnose your problems.

Comment: i have a c++ code and i run the code in the terminal ./executedfile inputargument.txt but i want to have a bash script that can run ./executedfile inputargument.txt without having to type ./executedfile inputargument.txt inside the terminal

Comment: So write that into your script file. What's the problem actually?

Comment: writing the bash script is the problem.

Comment: I really don't get you? You just write these commands you'd type into the terminal in a script file, set the executable flag and run it from the bash.

Comment: You can just create an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like πάντα ῥεῖ said, just put the command in the script so it would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./executedfile inputargument.txt
```

After you write the script either do `sudo chmod a+x nameOfBASHScriptHere` or run it with `sh nameOfBASHScriptHere`.

What's the problem with that script? Please be specific.